# Ubuntu Touch Development: DBus connection via apparmor-template=unconfined?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, dbus, apparmor

I am trying to send DBus messages via Ubuntu Touch C++ application. With configuring default template (no error with `unconfined`) for Apparmor file my application is getting following error as reply:

```
QDBusMessage(type=Error, service="", error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied", error message="An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient, 0 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.278" (uid=32011 pid=28575 comm="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmlscene $@ s") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="DefaultAdapter" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=824 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")", signature="", contents=([]) )

phablet@ubuntu-phablet:/etc/apparmor.d$ aa-easyprof  --policy-vendor=ubuntu --policy-version=1.2 --list-templates
default
ubuntu-push-helper
ubuntu-scope-network
ubuntu-sdk
ubuntu-webapp
unconfined
```

My question: Do I have to configure Apparmor template with value `unconfined` even though the Ubuntu review will reject the upload package (and will do a manual review probably)? Or is there any way to create an own template for Ubuntu Touch click packages?

Comment: Just edit the *.apparmor in your project. Add rights that are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.
This is what I did. See `manifest.json.in`:

```js
{
    "policy_groups": [
        "networking"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1.2,
    "template": "unconfined"
}
```

Thus following ways worked for me for muting BQ phone by any Ubuntu Touch application, but only by specifying the security template as unconfined.

1. Launch pulse audio command:

   ```cpp
   [...]
   myProcess = new QProcess(this);
   connect (myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(printOutput()));
   connect (myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(printError()));
   QString cmd("/usr/bin/pactl");
   QStringList arguments;
   arguments.append(QString("set-sink-mute"));
   arguments.append(QString("0"));
   arguments.append(QString(muted?"1":"0"));
   myProcess->start(QString(cmd), arguments);
   ```
2. Send DBus message:

   ```cpp
   QDBusInterface handlerPropertiesInterface("org.freedesktop.Accounts", "/org/freedesktop/Accounts/User32011", "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties", QDBusConnection::systemBus());
   handlerPropertiesInterface.call("Set", "com.ubuntu.touch.AccountsService.Sound", "SilentMode", QVariant::fromValue(QDBusVariant(muted)));
   ```

To my mind it would be better to have a specific template for sending DBus messages (other than "wide" unconfined template), right? Or is it possible to define own security templates?